# requires plug-in "org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.7.0)", or later version

Tags: android

I am getting this error while trying configure Android with Eclipse.

Android Development Tools (22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508) requires plug-in org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.7.0), or later version.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Download V3.7.0 or later install it. [Here is a link](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.core/runtime/3.7.0) for downloading the plugins. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: You mean Eclipse Version 3.7.0 ?

Comment: No. org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.7.0.v20110110.jar. You can see it at the top of the page.